# Pandas Dataframe keep the most recent incidence

Tags: pandas, sorting, drop

I have below df, i want to keep the most recent incidence for the ID. Incident range from 1 - 3. 1 is most recent and 3 is least.

| ID | Incident |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 |
| 001 | 2 |
| 001 | 3 |
| 002 | 1 |
| 002 | 1 |
| 002 | 1 |
| 002 | 1 |
| 002 | 3 |
| A003 | 2 |
| A003 | 2 |
| A003 | 3 |

Output

| ID | Incident |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 |
| 002 | 1 |
| 002 | 1 |
| 002 | 1 |
| 002 | 1 |
| A003 | 2 |
| A003 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first group your dataset based on your ID, and select the minimum for each group using [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `min()`.

Then you join this result with your original dataframe using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and with parameter `indicator` set to `True` which will show which rows belong to the minimum values.

Last step will be to using `loc` to filter your dataframe will get you your answer:

```
m = df.groupby('ID',as_index=False).agg({'Incident':'min'})
out = df.loc[pd.merge(df,m,how='left',indicator=True)._merge.eq('both')]
```

prints back:

```
print(out)

     ID  Incident
0     1         1
3     2         1
4     2         1
5     2         1
6     2         1
8  A003         2
9  A003         2
```